# textview does not display seconds counting down Android

Tags: java, android, timer, textview, countdowntimer

i have a textview that has a int number of seconds to count down from all the way to 0. i pass in a random number selected by a user to the timer and it counts down to 0. so i pass the variable **S** into timer

my textview:

```
 mSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsLabel);
```

my timer:

```
int s = //int taken from on spinner in another class

Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, s * 1000);

    new CountDownTimer(s, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mSeconds.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            finish();
        }
    };
```

my textview does not display anything at all? how can i get it to show the seconds counting down?

Comment: Start you `CountDownTimer` using `start()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not starting the `CountDownTimer`.

Do this

```
new CountDownTimer(s, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mSeconds.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        finish();
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: it says android.view.WindowLeaked: in my log but no crashes

Comment: Try commenting `finish()` method in `onFinish()`

Comment: yes no more errors in log but the seconds still do not show? im not sure why

Comment: i did not put s*1000 in new countdowntimer thats why was not showing

Answer (score 1):

Start your count down timer

```
    CountDownTimer ct = new CountDownTimer(s, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mSeconds.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            finish();
        }
    };
    ct.start();
```

Comment: If your millisInFuture < countDownInterval the you won't receive tick..i.e. you should pass `s` > 1000 in `CountDownTimer ct = new CountDownTimer(s, 1000)`

Answer (score -1):

You should manage it on **UI thread**